# Is whitespace between the two ='s in an equality operator legal in C++?

Tags: c++, whitespace, equality-operator

I am currently learning C++ from 'Problem solving with C++' (9th, W. Savitch). The book shows an example of a while loop. The while loop looks as follows.

```
while (ans = = 'Y' || ans = = 'y')
{
    //compound statement
}
```

`ans` is of type `char`. 
The boolean expression appears to be trying to use the equality operator, and in the context of the `//compound statement` this makes sense. However, I always thought whitespace was illegal within the equality operator. i.e `==` is legal, but `= =` is illegal.

When I copy the code and compile it, my compiler throws the error 'expected expression' when it hits `= =` as if I am trying to assign an expression to a variable. I am almost certain this is a typo within the book. However, just in case the book is trying to throw a curveball I thought I would ask...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is whitespace between the two ='s in an equality operator legal in C++?

No. `= =` is two `=` tokens. `==` is one `==` token. You can't use the former when you mean the latter.

Comment: One might add that the tokenization phase is, at least conceptually, distinct and comes before any semantics kick in. Humans see that ignoring the space between the `=`s makes the program make sense, but the compiler cannot -- and is not allowed to -- see that because it doesn't try to make sense of the program during tokenization. The stage which *does* try to make sense, otoh, doesn't see the source any more; it sees a sequence of tokens which don't make sense.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks. So I'm sticking with typo then? I.e in no case would it ever be necessary to use `= =`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thanks for the additional info!